# Временной лимит в MySQL при импорте БД

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, apache, phpmyadmin

Сервер 5.7.25- ubuntu 0.16.04.2, Apache/2.4.18, PHP 7.0.32

При импорте БД выдает: "**Достигнут временной лимит. Если вы хотите завершить импорт, перезапустите его выбрав тот же файл...**"

Однако при выборе того же файла и попытке продолжения импорта, процедура заканчивается с ошибками.

В **php.ini** *max_execution_time* и *max_input_time* изменил на 0, но толку не дало.

В **/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php** прописал $cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 0; толку "0"

Пробовал утилиту **Sypex Dumper**, но она не работает с PHP7

Как импортировтаь базу данных, что еще можно сделать? Прошу помощи

Comment: `mysql -u username -p database_name < file.sql` команда гениальная своей простотой

Comment: database_name - имя базы, куда нужно производит импорт? а к file.sql нужно прописывать полный путь на сервере, где лежит импортируемая база?

Comment: Именно так. Путь можно не прописывать, если вы исполняете программу в директории импортируемого файла

Comment: Спасибо, хороший вариант. Наверное, лучший. Если оформите как ответ, отмечу как решение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Совет от @ArchDemon прекрасно справился с задачей:

```
mysql -u username -p database_name < file.sq
```